# google container cluster giving auth error while creation

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Below is the error coming while creating a cluster:

> (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Request had insufficient authentication 
>   scopes

Comment: I have a free tier account but whenever i try to create a container cluster i am getting below error from one of the script

**(gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Request had insufficient authentication 
scopes.**

for other script it is giving similar error. 

: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes., forbidden

May i know how i can resolve this ?

Comment: i was unable to write in text so i explained in comment . Can anyone help ?

Comment: You should edit your question and put it all in there.  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IAM roles for the "Compute Engine default service account" and make sure it has enough permission to run the command [2]. Usually it would have an owner or editor role.

If you are on the Google Cloud Console, when creating an instance you need to look for the 'Identity and API access' section, and select 'Allow full access to all Cloud APIs' [1]

[1]https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances?hl=en_US&_ga=2.168486115.-390700867.1538154355 
[2]https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts